# Prevent use of default constructor on generated web service proxy

Tags: c#, code-generation, asmx, .net-1.1, webservice-client

I've got a situation where I have several web services that I need to consume. I need the ability to perform custom actions in the constructor of the proxy before any calls are made (assigning the configured URL, assigning the SOAP header, etc.).

My first solution is to create a child class that derives from the generated proxy, then make those actions in the constructor of the child class. That way, app code can call the constructor of the child, and get a valid proxy that has the stuff I need.

I'm trying to prevent the app code from calling the constructor of the generated proxy, so people don't accidentally instantiate the proxy without doing my custom stuff. My first thought is to move the generated code into a separate assembly from the child, and make sure the app code only has a reference to the child assembly. This works for the most part, but...

The services contain complex types, defined in the proxy. I need the app code to reference these classes, which means the app code needs a reference to the base assembly anyway, which means they now have access to the generated constructor.

I've tried an overly-complex solution of wrapping each of the generated complex types in an interface, and then hiding the real calls and replacing them with copies of the object as the interface type. This worked once or twice, but it gets ugly really quick.

It seems that the only way I can have everything I want is to remove the public constructor of the generated proxy, and replace it with a protected constructor, then allow a reference to this assembly - they'll be able to work with the complex types, but won't be able to call the constructor. My problem is that the only way I can think of to do this is to manipulate the generated code to change the constructor.

Any ideas? I'm using WSDL.exe to generate the proxies, and there's no option there to hide the constructor. Is there another way that I'm just missing? I suppose I can write a tool to automatically modify the proxy immediately after it's generated, but that just feels ugly to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with modifying the proxy generated code to make the constructor protected instead of public. The call to WSDL.exe was handled in an automated project already, so it wasn't that big of a deal. This was really the only way I could get everything I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Are you stuck using .NET 2.0? If not, then you shouldn't be using WSDL.EXE. You should be using SVCUTIL.EXE or "Add Service Reference".

Instead of creating a derived class, you should create your own wrapper classes, which use the proxy classes. One would use something like `MyWrapper.CreateProxy()`, which would return a properly-configured instance of the proxy class.

BTW, WSDL.EXE creates proxies using the legacy "ASMX" technology, which has no ability to use the types from the service.

Comment: Thanks - I'm actually upgrading from .NET 1.1 to .NET 4.0 - there's already a huge configuration set up for the services. Looking at svcutil, I believe it would require significant configuration changes, which we're not able to make at the moment.

Comment: Also, the generated class seems to require the SoapHeader object to be passed into every service method - so if my wrapper just returned the proxy itself, the app code would have to create that SoapHeader object every time, which is one of the things I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing that, why can't you override the GetWebRequest method? It will be called before the service method call anyways.

If you have added a service reference, implementing message inspector will do same thing.

Comment: Aah...got confused with HTTP headers. :doh: